# Cannot resume from suspend

Tags: suspend

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Hp Pavillion and whenever I enter suspend mode, my session is not resumed.All I get is a black screen.I have looked up other answers but they don't work.

Comment: What kind of graphics card does the computer have? Have you installed "Additional Drivers" for the graphics card? Please update your questions with details.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here but with 13.10 64bit, however the problem for me was the Nouveau display driver.

I am using Nvidia, and moved to a proprietary Nvidia driver, rebooted and suspend now works fine.

So I would suggest checking what driver you are using and changing to the proprietary driver available for your system.

Check in: SYSTEM SETTINGS / SOFTWARE & UPDATES / ADDITIONAL DRIVERS